# WooCommerce How to add email recipient based on a variable attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add different email recipients based on the product variation attribute that a customer has selected. I have the following codes but it is not working at the moment.

```
 function sv_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
   
        
 foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
           
           $variation = wc_get_product($item['variation_id']);
           $variation_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
           
           if($variation == "Branch" && $variation_attributes == "BT" ) $recipient .= 'bt@email.com';
           elseif ($variation == "Branch" && $variation_attributes == "PW" ) $recipient .= 'pw@email.com';
           elseif ($variation == "Branch" && $variation_attributes == "TP" ) $recipient .= 'tp@email.com';
           return $recipient;
        }
        
       
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 15, 2 );
```

I appreciate it if someone can help to point out what is the issue, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
function sv_conditional_email_recipient($recipient, $order, $email) {


    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

        $variation = wc_get_product($item['variation_id']);
        $variation_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();

        foreach ($variation_attributes as $variation_attr_key => $variation_attr_value) {
            if ('BT' === $variation_attr_value) {
                $recipient .= ', bt@email.com';
            }
            if ('PW' === $variation_attr_value) {
                $recipient .= ', pw@email.com';
            }
            if ('TP' === $variation_attr_value) {
                $recipient .= ', tp@email.com';
            }
        }
        return $recipient;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 15, 3);
```